# What is Linker binary name used by Yocto Linux

Tags: linux, linker, linux-kernel

I am looking for Linker binary used by Yocto-Linux ,In normal Linux you can find it in somewhere /lib dir but not sure how to find it for Yocto Linux.

Anyone can tell me how should you go about it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean the dynamic linker. Try running [ldd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html), e.g. on some common executable:

```
  ldd /bin/sh
```

(you could also guess what dynamic linker you use by running `cat /proc/self/maps`)

The ordinary linker, the one you use to build programs from objects, is usually called thru the compiler: you use `gcc` both for compiling and for linking. (in fact, `gcc` is just a driving program to start `cc1` - the real compiler, or `ld` or `collect2` - the linkers; use `gcc -v` to find out which commands are started).